# relation between toValue and inputRange in animation

Tags: javascript, react-native

In animation,what is the relation with toValue and inputRange?

```
 this.step1 = new Animated.Value(0);

 Animated.timing(this.buttonBottom,{
    toValue : 140,
    duration : 2000,
    easing : Easing.back(),
  }).start();
  const step1x = this.step1.interpolate({
    inputRange : [0,1],
    outputRange : [0,90],
  })
```

In this case,what is the defferences in case `inputRange[0,1]` and `inputRange[0,2]`.
`inputRange` and `toValue` must be equal?

Comment: Hi John Miller ! And welcome to StackOverFlow ! Can you give us more context ? Where this function came from ? Is this from a addon or library ? Can you provide us the link ?  And don't forget to have a look at your https://stackoverflow.com/conduct ☺️

Comment: And you can have a look there it seems to answers your question https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations